# nfs quarantine after Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, nfs

After upgrading to Catalina - my NFS mounts seem to gain the quarantine attribute when writing files to the drive with OSX applications:

```
MBP:sourceimages root# ls -las@ test0*
1282 -rw-r--r--@ 1 mtwomey  65534  655911 Nov  3 12:49 test01.afdesign
    com.apple.quarantine        32
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags     42
1282 -rw-r--r--@ 1 mtwomey  65534  655912 Nov  3 12:51 test02.afdesign
    com.apple.quarantine        32
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags     42
1282 -rw-r--r--@ 1 mtwomey  65534  655888 Nov  3 12:52 test03.afdesign
    com.apple.quarantine        32
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags     42
1282 -rw-r--r--@ 1 mtwomey  65534  655888 Nov  3 12:53 test04.afdesign
    com.apple.quarantine        32
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags     42
1282 -rw-r--r--@ 1 mtwomey  65534  655888 Nov  3 12:53 test05.afdesign
    com.apple.quarantine        32
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags     42
MBP:sourceimages root#
```

This is creating all sorts of issues when trying to work with these files. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but Howard Oalkey has a couple of utilities to help with this, [Sandstrip](https://eclecticlight.co/tag/sandstrip/) and [Pratique](https://eclecticlight.co/tag/pratique/) (as well as some good discussion/analysis of what's going on).

Comment: That's quite interesting @Gordon Davisson - something to dig into a bit anyhow, thank you.